# Why is stringValue failing here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I'm trying to bring data into my app from an external file. everything's working until I add the event.title (the 3rd objectAtIndex below). I think I'm incorrectly using "stringValue" and it should be something else. the floatValues work fine.

```
event.latitude = [[values objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

event.longitude = [[values objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

event.title = [[values objectAtIndex:2] stringValue];
```

here's the header file code:

```
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    NSString *title;
}

@property (nonatomic) float latitude;
@property (nonatomic) float longitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strings, you don't need to get stringValue or anything. floatValue is for NSNumber, but you already have a plain NSString.

```
event.title = [values objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the string stored in the file, and how are you reading the file?

I would assume you can just drop the `stringValue` method and directly assign the return from `objectAtIndex:` - assuming the object is read in as a string.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing that out. i didn't see that option before.